# Script Exporting Policies and Conditions

Tags: sql-server-2008, powershell, smo

I would like to automatically script out all SQL Server 2008 policies and conditions on a server each night and compare the files to my version control system.  In the UI, I can script out individual policies by right-clicking the policy and selecting Export Policy.  Is it possible to script out policies and conditions via SMO or PowerShell?

Ideally, I would like to incorporate this into my existing PowerShell script that generates scripts for all of my other server and database objects.  Here's the script that currently does this action:

```
# Load needed assemblies 
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO") | out-null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMOExtended")| Out-Null; 

#Specify target server and databases.
$sql_server = "SomeServerName"
$SMOserver = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server -ArgumentList "$sql_server"
$databases = $SMOserver.Databases
$BaseSavePath = "T:\SomeFilePath\" + $sql_server + "\"

#Remove existing objects.
Remove-Item $BaseSavePath -Recurse

#Script server-level objects.
$ServerSavePath = $BaseSavePath
$ServerObjects = $SMOserver.BackupDevices
$ServerObjects += $SMOserver.Endpoints
$ServerObjects += $SMOserver.JobServer.Jobs
$ServerObjects += $SMOserver.LinkedServers
$ServerObjects += $SMOserver.Triggers

foreach ($ScriptThis in $ServerObjects | where {!($_.IsSystemObject)}) 
{
    #Need to Add Some mkDirs for the different $Fldr=$ScriptThis.GetType().Name 
    $scriptr = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Scripter') ($SMOserver)
    $scriptr.Options.AppendToFile = $True
    $scriptr.Options.AllowSystemObjects = $False
    $scriptr.Options.ClusteredIndexes = $True
    $scriptr.Options.DriAll = $True
    $scriptr.Options.ScriptDrops = $False
    $scriptr.Options.IncludeHeaders = $False
    $scriptr.Options.ToFileOnly = $True
    $scriptr.Options.Indexes = $True
    $scriptr.Options.Permissions = $True
    $scriptr.Options.WithDependencies = $False

    <#Script the Drop too#>
    $ScriptDrop = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Scripter') ($SMOserver)
    $ScriptDrop.Options.AppendToFile = $True
    $ScriptDrop.Options.AllowSystemObjects = $False
    $ScriptDrop.Options.ClusteredIndexes = $True
    $ScriptDrop.Options.DriAll = $True
    $ScriptDrop.Options.ScriptDrops = $True
    $ScriptDrop.Options.IncludeHeaders = $False
    $ScriptDrop.Options.ToFileOnly = $True
    $ScriptDrop.Options.Indexes = $True
    $ScriptDrop.Options.WithDependencies = $False

    <#This section builds folder structures.  Remove the date folder if you want to overwrite#>
    $TypeFolder=$ScriptThis.GetType().Name
    if ((Test-Path -Path "$ServerSavePath\$TypeFolder") -eq "true") `
            {"Scripting Out $TypeFolder $ScriptThis"} `
        else {new-item -type directory -name "$TypeFolder"-path "$ServerSavePath"}
    $ScriptFile = $ScriptThis -replace ":", "-" -replace "\\", "-" 
    $ScriptDrop.Options.FileName = $ServerSavePath + "\" + $TypeFolder + "\" + $ScriptFile.Replace("]", "").Replace("[", "") + ".sql"
    $scriptr.Options.FileName = $ServerSavePath + "\" + $TypeFolder + "\" + $ScriptFile.Replace("]", "").Replace("[", "") + ".sql"

    #This is where each object actually gets scripted one at a time.
    $ScriptDrop.Script($ScriptThis)
    $scriptr.Script($ScriptThis)
} #This ends the object scripting loop at the server level.


#Script database-level objects.
foreach ($db in $databases)
{
    $DatabaseObjects = $db.ApplicationRoles
    $DatabaseObjects += $db.Assemblies
    $DatabaseObjects += $db.ExtendedStoredProcedures
    $DatabaseObjects += $db.ExtendedProperties
    $DatabaseObjects += $db.PartitionFunctions
    $DatabaseObjects += $db.PartitionSchemes
    $DatabaseObjects += $db.Roles
    $DatabaseObjects += $db.Rules
    $DatabaseObjects += $db.Schemas
    $DatabaseObjects += $db.StoredProcedures
    $DatabaseObjects += $db.Synonyms
    $DatabaseObjects += $db.Tables
    $DatabaseObjects += $db.Triggers
    $DatabaseObjects += $db.UserDefinedAggregates
    $DatabaseObjects += $db.UserDefinedDataTypes
    $DatabaseObjects += $db.UserDefinedFunctions
    $DatabaseObjects += $db.UserDefinedTableTypes
    $DatabaseObjects += $db.UserDefinedTypes
    $DatabaseObjects += $db.Users
    $DatabaseObjects += $db.Views

    #Build this portion of the directory structure out here.  Remove the existing directory and its contents first.
    $DatabaseSavePath = $BaseSavePath + "Databases\" + $db.Name

    new-item -type directory -path "$DatabaseSavePath"

    foreach ($ScriptThis in $DatabaseObjects | where {!($_.IsSystemObject)}) 
    {
        #Need to Add Some mkDirs for the different $Fldr=$ScriptThis.GetType().Name 
        $scriptr = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Scripter') ($SMOserver)
        $scriptr.Options.AppendToFile = $True
        $scriptr.Options.AllowSystemObjects = $False
        $scriptr.Options.ClusteredIndexes = $True
        $scriptr.Options.DriAll = $True
        $scriptr.Options.ScriptDrops = $False
        $scriptr.Options.IncludeHeaders = $False
        $scriptr.Options.ToFileOnly = $True
        $scriptr.Options.Indexes = $True
        $scriptr.Options.Permissions = $True
        $scriptr.Options.WithDependencies = $False

        <#Script the Drop too#>
        $ScriptDrop = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Scripter') ($SMOserver)
        $ScriptDrop.Options.AppendToFile = $True
        $ScriptDrop.Options.AllowSystemObjects = $False
        $ScriptDrop.Options.ClusteredIndexes = $True
        $ScriptDrop.Options.DriAll = $True
        $ScriptDrop.Options.ScriptDrops = $True
        $ScriptDrop.Options.IncludeHeaders = $False
        $ScriptDrop.Options.ToFileOnly = $True
        $ScriptDrop.Options.Indexes = $True
        $ScriptDrop.Options.WithDependencies = $False

        <#This section builds folder structures.  Remove the date folder if you want to overwrite#>
        $TypeFolder=$ScriptThis.GetType().Name
        if ((Test-Path -Path "$DatabaseSavePath\$TypeFolder") -eq "true") `
                {"Scripting Out $TypeFolder $ScriptThis"} `
            else {new-item -type directory -name "$TypeFolder"-path "$DatabaseSavePath"}
        $ScriptFile = $ScriptThis -replace ":", "-" -replace "\\", "-"
        $ScriptDrop.Options.FileName = $DatabaseSavePath + "\" + $TypeFolder + "\" + $ScriptFile.Replace("]", "").Replace("[", "") + ".sql"
        $scriptr.Options.FileName = $DatabaseSavePath + "\" + $TypeFolder + "\" + $ScriptFile.Replace("]", "").Replace("[", "") + ".sql"

        #This is where each object actually gets scripted one at a time.
        $ScriptDrop.Script($ScriptThis)
        $scriptr.Script($ScriptThis)

    } #This ends the object scripting loop.
} #This ends the database loop.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of choices from SMO/Powershell.

1: SQLPS/PowerShell with SQL loaded
SQLSERVER:\SQLPolicy\\DEFAULT\Policies

you can then dig through it, i didnt see an "export" but you can certianly get the info out of it.

2: SMO 
basically SMO has a Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DMF namespace that has severial policy objects (what you end up with in the PowerShell side of things) Policy, PolicyStore, PolicyCondition etc, rather than write out an example, you can find one here.
http://rdbmsexperts.com/Blogs/archives/295

again i didnt see an "export" method anywhere, but you could probably spit out what you needed easily enough.

Comment: I've checked sqlps and it doesn't appear there is any way to script out an object from it.  SMO is probably the solution since you can create policies with it (as shown in your link) and my example uses SMO to script out all other database objects, but I have yet to see an example of how to script out policies via SMO.  If I can get an example of how to script out policies and conditions via SMO, then I will happily accept it as the answer.

Comment: you'll need to do it by hand, there is no export. basically they expose all the objects and a too string for each.. so basically you pull in the policy, then the properties of the policy (conditions mostly)